# Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK - Need admin approval, unverified needs permission to access resources in your organization

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks, powershell-7.2

I am new to the [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

The commands below all launch a browser tab where I am prompted to login.

I login with my Microsoft account which has these roles:

- SharePoint Administrator
- Global Reader
- Power Platform Administrator

The account is also specified as an `Admin` of the global term store taxonomy.

*In order to list all sites in a tenant ([List sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)), I try to connect with:*

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Read.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
```

*In order to export term store taxonomy ([Get store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-store-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)), I try to connect with:*

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "TermStore.Read.All", "TermStore.ReadWrite.All"
```

In both these instance, after logging in with my admin account, I am getting the error shown below in the browser:

```
Need admin approval

unverified

needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. 

Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it
```

[image]

I do not get this error when connecting with the following:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All"
```

**Troubleshooting**

Perhaps the research below can shed some light on an answer as to why this is happening and how to resolve it?

If I look at the docs for the Graph API endpoints I am wanting to query, I can see the `Permissions` are as follows:

[List sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

| Permission type | Permissions (from least to most privileged) |
| --- | --- |
| Delegated (work or school account) | Not supported. |
| Delegated (personal Microsoft account) | Not supported. |
| Application | Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All |

[Get store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-store-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

| Permission type | Permissions (from least to most privileged) |
| --- | --- |
| Delegated (work or school account) | TermStore.Read.All, TermStore.ReadWrite.All |
| Delegated (personal Microsoft account) | Not supported. |
| Application | Not supported. |

How do these permissions relate to using the Graph PowerShell SDK?

Per [the quote below from the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0#authentication), I believe using the SDK as I have above is considered `delegated access`?

> The PowerShell SDK supports two types of authentication: delegated
> access, and app-only access. In this guide, you'll use delegated
> access to sign in as a user, grant consent to the SDK to act on your
> behalf, and call the Microsoft Graph.

So I guess my scenario is `Delegated (work or school account)`?

**Questions**

**01)**  If so, does that mean I cannot make any request where the API docs define the `Permissions` as:

| Permission type | Permissions (from least to most privileged) |
| --- | --- |
| Delegated (work or school account) | Not supported. |

**02)**  If that is the case, does that mean that the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK is not a good tool for administering SharePoint Online (because, according to the API reference docs, many of the endpoints are 'not supported' by a `Delegated (work or school account)`)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching out to us , this looks like you are not using your admin account, please cross check the account you are logging in PowerShell. please follow below steps .

1. Try to disconnect your previous account from PowerShell (use command Disconnect-MgGraph)
2. Then try connect with your account ,use Connect-MgGraph
3. You will get a pop up , select the account in which you are the admin.
4. Then run the command and try again

[image]

**Edited :**

Agree with scottwtang comments ,If you are using the correct account make sure admin consent requests are Enabled in your tenant , you can check by following the below steps and ask your Global Administrator to grant admin consent

To check the admin consent workflow and choose reviewers:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal with one of the roles listed in the
   prerequisites.
2. Search for and select Azure Active Directory.
3. Select Enterprise applications.
4. Under Manage, select User settings. Under Admin consent requests,
   select Yes for Users can request admin consent to apps they are
   unable to consent to . Configure admin consent workflow settings
   ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow

[image]

Hope this help ,
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, however I am definitely using my admin account, it is a very recognisable account name.  Are you able to connect using those 2 example connection commands I provided?

Comment: Yes , I am able to add the permission through the above commands , i am wondering what's going wrong , could you please try once in graph explorer?

Comment: The implication regarding the "error" is that user consent and admin consent requests are disabled in your tenant - you need a Global Administrator to grant admin consent to the Microsoft Graph PowerShell application for the delegated permissions `Sites.Read.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`, `TermStore.Read.All`, `TermStore.ReadWrite.All`. Most likely the other 2 permissions have already been granted the admin consent.

Comment: Hi @user1063287 , as scottwang suggested to enable the admin consent in your tenant  , i am adding the steps on my answer , please check my edited answer. Thanks

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding this.  I have the SharePoint Administrator role and therefore have the permissions required on the resources defined.  Why do I need a global admin to enable a setting which allows users *without adequate permissions* the ability to request them?  I have been reading articles on different consent ‘flows’ but the answer is still not clear to me.  I’m not sure why a global admin consent is required, when my SharePoint Administrator role should be enough.

Comment: If you are trying to provide add the scope "TermStore.ReadWrite.All " and consenting on behalf of your organization , for this you need to enable admin consent ,only admin can approved the permission otherwise you have to ask other admin to approve , and as per your screenshot above added you were getting error : "needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant".

Comment: Wow! Thank you!
For some reason this time my Admin account needed Global Administrator elevation...   which I haven't needed before.